# EL 2.1 and DCEVM full version

Tags: java, jsp, dcevm

i'm trying to use dcevm in an already existing project: we are developing using jboss 5.1, struts 1.1.

The problem is that, if i add a method in a java bean, dcevm successfully swap my class and i can use it without restarting jboss, BUT, when the method is called in a jsp, it's not seen.

How can i make my jsp's see the change in the java bean signature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[HotswapAgent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/) has plugin for EL. It clears internal EL caches when you reload some class.

Comment: HotswapAgent only support Apache, JBoss and Juel UEL.

Comment: Which implementation do you have?